# AJAX SUBMIT not send

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

This is my code, but doesn't work?
anyone has any ideas to make it work?

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).parsley('validate')) {
         $('#contactResult').slideToggle('slow', function () {
             $("#contactResult").html('<div class="center">   WAIT!!!!  </div>');
             $("#contactForm").ajaxSubmit({
                 target: "#contactResult"
             });
             $("#contactResult").slideToggle("slow");
         });

     }
 });
```

For this I have implemented ajax submit
jquery.form.js

```
     $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).parsley('validate') ) {
                            $.post("contact.php", $(this).serialize());       

            }
        });*/
```

with this work perfectly!!

but i necessity slidetoggle effect

Comment: What does not work/ Do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: 0 error in console :|

Comment: What happens when you change ajaxSubmit to post, same as the second example?

Comment: send 2 email ... but ajaxSubmit send void result